# Jquery calculate in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make calculations in the rows of the table. But I have some problems. Let's look at the picture below.

[image: Sample]

It was supposed to be 26.8. Every time I click on the last row I get the data on the line.

Comment: should we guess the error in your code ? or will you provide the code ...

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. What exactly in the table are you calculating. Can you post some of the problem code where you think it is not working.

Comment: welcome to SO . please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . we don't have a crystal ball or something like that. so you need to share all relevant code and ideally make a working snippet

Comment: A hint would be that your sum is equal to n times the last value, but like the others said, you must provide your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the codes yesterday. sorry

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".AddRow").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                var row = $('#deger tr:last');
                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    url: '/Home/Ekle/' + id,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (besin) {

                        //I create the rows of the table
                        $("#deger tr:last").before("<tr><td style='height:30px;line-height:30px'>" + besin.BesinAd +
                            "</td><td style='height:30px;line-height:30px'>" + besin.KHDeger + "x" + besin.KHGram +
                            "</td><td style='height:30px;line-height:30px' class='hKh'>" + besin.KHDeger +
                            "</td><td style='height:30px;line-height:30px'  class='hGr'>" + besin.KHGram +
                            "</td><td style='height:30px;line-height:30px'><input type='text' class='form-control input-xs txtHesap'></input></td><td style='height:30px;line-height:30px'><button  class='btn btn-success btn-xs sil'>Sil</button></td></tr>");
                        $(".txtHesap").focus();


                        /*Actions to be performed when a value is entered in the textbox
                        Where only the last added line gets its value. That's my problem.*/

                        $("#deger").on('input', '.txtHesap', function () {
                            var toplam = 0;
                            var khgr = besin.KHGram; //Values ​​from the controller
                            var kh = besin.KHDeger;  //Values ​​from the controller

                            $("#deger .txtHesap").each(function () {
                                var gr = $(this).val();
                                if ($.isNumeric(gr)) {
                                    toplam += parseFloat((gr * kh) / khgr);
                                }
                            });

                            $("#toplam").html(toplam.toFixed(2));
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```